# Desire to use ALC892 multiple independent outputs with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, hdmi, realtek

I am attempting to migrate my Home Theater Desktop PC from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 20.04. I have a dual boot system using two SSD, one with Windows 7, the other Ubuntu 20.04. On Windows 7, independent sound outputs available and (usage) are:

1. Realtek Line Out Rear (speakers)
2. Realtek 2nd Out Front (headphones)
3. Realtek Digital Out Optical (A/V receiver)
4. Nvidia HDMI (Hisense Android TV)

I would like to have the same independent outputs available with Ubuntu 20.04 so applications could use them as follows:

1. Default output be Realtek Line Out Rear (speakers) - Analog 2.0 used by applications such as Firefox browser.
2. Realtek 2nd out Front (headphones) - Analog 2.0 used by audio/video editing applications such as Audacity and Open Shot to hear audio nuances in headphones while editing
3. Realtek Digital Out Optical (A/V receiver) - Digital 2.0 with surround passthru used by Rhythmbox or other audio application to play high quality music through Yamaha RX-840 Receiver
4. Nvidia HDMI (Hisense Android TV) - Digital 5.1 used by Kodi or other video application to play movies on TV with surround sound.

I have used alsamixer to verify that all the ALC892 outputs are unmuted and at max volume.
pavucontrol shows:
Output Devices
1. GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)
   Port: HDMI/Display Port (plugged in)
   Profile: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI2) Output
2. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
   Port: Line Out (plugged in)
   Profile: Analog Stereo Output

Applications such as Firefox play through the analog line out to speakers.
Kodi will only output sound when "Default PULSEAUDIO" is selected as the Audio device.
I've read through other related questions and answers - I get lost with most of them. I've tried making changes with pavucontrol but can't get the multiple independent outputs. I'm not sure how but once I had the same Firefox audio simultaneously from the Realtek Line Out Rear, 2nd Out Front, and Digital Out Optical ports so I know the Realtek ALC892 hardware is working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Has anyone made a pulseaudio configuration with multiple independent outputs for the Realtek ALC892? The following image shows the [Home Theater Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESiEm.jpg)

Comment: I never found a solution to the sound problem with Ubuntu 20.04 so I am unable to migrate my Home Theater PC to Ubuntu 20.04. It is a must requirement to have all the multiple sound outputs working independently.

Comment: I am now directing my attention to building a replacement streaming media server using Ubuntu 20.04, and the latest versions of apache2, icecast2, shoutcast, and liquidsoap. The old server used Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with ALC892 on a MSI B450-Pro, under Debian 10. It should work with ubuntu as well.

In `/etc/modprobe.d/hda-jack-retask.conf` put the following content:

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 patch=hda-hint.fw,hda-hint.fw,hda-hint.fw,hda-hint.fw
```

the `power_save` option is up to you, you can skip it if you're not hearing any clicks or weird fade-ins when the sound starts

In `/lib/firmware/hda-hint.fw` put the following content:

```
[codec]
0x10ec0892 0x14629b86 0

[hint]
add_jack_modes = yes
indep_hp = yes
```

These are documented in the [linux kernel hd audio notes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/sound/hd-audio/notes.html). You can probably skip `add_jack_modes` too, but I found it useful.

Next, in `alsamixer`, you will have more options, specifically the "Independent HP" option (HP stands for HeadPhones). `aplay -l` should now show two outputs.

Also, for recording from both inputs (front mic and line in), you'll have to enable them, in `alsamixer` press <kbd>F4</kbd> to go to the capture page, then hit <kbd>space</kbd> when selecting Capture and Capture 1 to enable them.